# How to edit your Word table properties

Tags: microsoft-word

I've been trying to edit my Word's table design but I couldn't achieve what I really was tending to. I'm trying to prevent the bolded words from being bolded automatically when creating a table in this format, so if Anyone could help with this I'll be thankful.

Also another question, How can I put a text\picture at the center when writing a thread here? like the picture down below.

Here is the table I'm trying to edit:

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Select Apply formatting to list: [![enter image description here][1]][1]

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zshct.png

Comment: Please see https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask.